# How to use the hammerspoon CLI?

Tags: lua, hammerspoon

I'd like to be able to run a command like `hs -m foo -c bar -- baz` and run some code using `bar` and/or `baz`. The `hs -h` help message says that `baz` should be available via `_cli._args` or `_cli.args`, but I can't figure out where the `_cli` value exists.

Here's the code I have:

```lua
local ipc = require('hs.ipc')

local port

function fooHandler()
    print('Hello, World!')
end

port = ipc.localPort('foo', fooHandler)
```

The output of `hs -m foo -c bar -- baz` is:

```
-- Legacy mode enabled --
nil
```

I'm sure there's a simple answer, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Although I was unable to figure out how to use it with a local port, I was able to figure out how it works with the default remote one. Here's the code:

```lua
require('hs.ipc')
function bar(arg)
  print("Hello from bar! The arg is ".. arg)
end
```

If you run `hs -c "bar('baz')"`, you'll get the following output:

```
Hello from bar! The arg is baz
```